# Assigning a function to a variable immediately prints echo? PHP

Tags: function, variables, printing, return, echo

I'm fairly new to PHP, so bear with me, this made me curious. I suppose my question is why does assigning the function to the variable print the echo of the function, and why doesn't it print the echo but only the return value when I echo the variable after assigning the function to it?

here is what I did:

```
function printStringReturnNumber(){ 
echo "how old are you?\\n"; 
return "27"; 
} 

$my_num = printStringReturnNumber();    //this prints the echo string of the function
$my_num;    //this prints the return value of the function
```

I expected echo $my_num to print the whole function. It seems when you assign a function to a variable it only prints the echo statement once, and then only prints the return value when you use it again.

thanks!

Comment: When you assign the function to `$my_num` it's running the function so you'll see "how old are you?", but the return value gets stored in $my_num. Printing $my_num later on will show the string 27 since the the value stored is "27" and not the whole function. In order to see the message again you would have to run the function again.